# SQL Bank DB: return only people with a given property

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, sqlplus

Created a banking DB, here is a link to the ER diagram:http://goo.gl/Auye7X, sorry that I couldn't just post the image in the question. So what I need to do is have a query that returns all customers who have a current account but not a saving account. It needs to be put out in a file using spool. So far, this is what I've got:

repheader 'Customer report'

repfooter 'Author Theo'

column customerID heading 'Customer ID'

column customerID format a10

column name heading 'Customer Name'

column name format a10

column current_acc heading 'Current Accounts'

column current_acc format 09999

set feedback off

spool customers.txt

select c.customerID, c.name, a.UAN, a.balance, a.overdraft

From customer c, current_acc a

Where c.customerID = a.customerID;

spool off

This does generate an output, but it has people who also have a savings account, and I'm just not sure what sort of logic to put in, so it only shows people who only have a current account. This is SQLPLUS, and I'm open to using PLSQL. Also, can someone just confirm this is the correct way to spool.

All help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this!

```
  select c.customerID, c.name, a.UAN, a.balance, a.overdraft
  From customer c join current_acc a
  on c.customerID = a.customerID and a ='current account'
```

Comment: Just tried that and it comes back saying ora-00904:"A": invalid identifier. I don't have a row in either table storing the type of account it is. Could you explain a bit more please. Thanks for the help btw :D!

Comment: Do you think using the 'minus' keyword might be of use?

Comment: OK! it's a join operation with a condition that it should return all values where current_acc a is `Current account`..it'd be more useful if you post the schema www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Sorry, don't have time to build the whole schema again just because I'm doing this for an exam tomorrow and I just tried to build a simple little table in sqlfiddle.com, but that didn't even work (probs because it was MYSQL), but thanks for that link as it looks like it'll be really good for future use! I did the schema in visio, and can upload that file, if that is of any use, which I doubt.

Comment: On SQLFiddle you can change the database type by clicking on the current database (default to MySQL 5.somthing-or-other, I believe) - a dropdown list will drop, and you can choose what you want (Oracle 11g is favorite :-). Share and enjoy.

Answer (score 0):

An inline view perhaps? Something like this:

```
select c.customerID, c.name, ca.UAN, ca.balance, ca.overdraft
from customer c, (select * from current_acc 
                  where customer_id not in 
                 (select customer_id from savings_acc)
                  ) ca
where c.customerID = ca.customerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select c.customerID, c.name, a.UAN, a.balance, a.overdraft
from customer c, current_acc a
where c.customer_id = a.customer_id
and not exists (select s.customer_id from saving_acc s
                where s.customer_id = c.customer_id)
```